# How parse json data in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to get json data from webapp :

I tried:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/postjson', methods = ['POST'])
def postJsonHandler():
    print (request.is_json)
    content = request.get_json()
    print (content)
    return 'JSON posted'

app.run(port= 8090)
```

and then:

```
import requests

url='http://127.0.0.1:8090/postjson'

hj=requests.post(url,{
 "device":"TemperatureSensor",
 "value":"20",
 "timestamp":"25/01/2017 10:10:05"
})

print(hj.text)
```

and i am getting:

on server side:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8090/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2018 01:45:54] "POST /postjson/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2018 01:46:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2018 01:46:01] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2018 01:51:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2018 01:51:47] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2018 01:52:26] "GET /postjson' HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2018 01:52:48] "GET /postjson/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

and client output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

I just want to post json and receive and save it to a variable at server side

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem. The code works for me. But one thing you should do (though it will probably not solve your 404 issue) is put `json=` before the dictionary in your requests call. Other than that I suggest stopping the server, verifying that the connection fails when running the client script, restarting the server, and trying again. By the way why are there logs for `/` and `/robots.txt`?

Comment: @AlexHall can you show me a little example like how i can send json via url in flask and then receive it on server side ?

Comment: I was saying you should write `requests.post(url, json={...})`, but the missing `json=` doesn't explain your 404 error and otherwise your code is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one issue in you post script . your need to set parameter  in `request.post` call i.e i.e  `hj=requests.post(url,json='some json')` 
it can also be seen from `requests.post` function definition  `def post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs):`  so in your case you were sending it as data not as json.

```
import requests

url='http://127.0.0.1:8090/postjson'

hj=requests.post(url,json = {
 "device":"TemperatureSensor",
 "value":"20",
 "timestamp":"25/01/2017 10:10:05"
})

print(hj.text)
```